# Highcharts align data label to x-axis if value is negative

Tags: javascript, html, graph, highcharts

I have a Highcharts graph that has data labels enabled. By default, the data labels are attached to the end of each data bar (see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyphun/NHCvW).

Is it possible to move the negative data labels and display them next to the x-axis instead of the end of the bar? Here is a doctored screen shot of what I would like to do:

http://cl.ly/image/2G3F0I2l2m1z

Here is a copy of my Highcharts example code:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
           plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        useHTML: true,
                        style: {
                            color: '#252525',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Column chart with negative values'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'';
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using stackLabels and doing some trick with setting y (position y) attribute of dataLabels. Also you should set verticalAlign of dataLabels to 'top'.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            style: {
                color: '#252525',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            verticalAlign : 'top',
            y: -15
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NHCvW/49/